# ARM program example with Keil Uvision startup file

Tags: assembly, arm, opcode, microprocessors, soc

Sorry, I am newbie, I am just starting to explore assembly with ARM. 
I am trying to run example from the book

```
        AREA Prog1, CODE, READONLY
        ENTRY
        MOV r0, #0x11 ; load initial value
        LSL r1, r0, #1 ; shift 1 bit left
        LSL r2, r1, #1 ; shift 1 bit left
stop    B stop ; stop program
        END
```

But as far as I know program should have RESET area vector set in order to start execution. 
So I added `Startup.s` file into my project

```
;/*****************************************************************************/
;/* STARTUP.S: Startup file for Philips LPC2000                               */
;/*****************************************************************************/
;/* <<< Use Configuration Wizard in Context Menu >>>                          */ 
;/*****************************************************************************/
;/* This file is part of the uVision/ARM development tools.                   */
;/* Copyright (c) 2005-2007 Keil Software. All rights reserved.               */
;/* This software may only be used under the terms of a valid, current,       */
;/* end user licence from KEIL for a compatible version of KEIL software      */
;/* development tools. Nothing else gives you the right to use this software. */
;/*****************************************************************************/


;/*
; *  The STARTUP.S code is executed after CPU Reset. This file may be 
; *  translated with the following SET symbols. In uVision these SET 
; *  symbols are entered under Options - ASM - Define.
; *
; *  REMAP: when set the startup code initializes the register MEMMAP 
; *  which overwrites the settings of the CPU configuration pins. The 
; *  startup and interrupt vectors are remapped from:
; *     0x00000000  default setting (not remapped)
; *     0x80000000  when EXTMEM_MODE is used
; *     0x40000000  when RAM_MODE is used
; *
; *  EXTMEM_MODE: when set the device is configured for code execution
; *  from external memory starting at address 0x80000000.
; *
; *  RAM_MODE: when set the device is configured for code execution
; *  from on-chip RAM starting at address 0x40000000.
; *
; *  EXTERNAL_MODE: when set the PIN2SEL values are written that enable
; *  the external BUS at startup.
; */


; Standard definitions of Mode bits and Interrupt (I & F) flags in PSRs

Mode_USR        EQU     0x10
Mode_FIQ        EQU     0x11
Mode_IRQ        EQU     0x12
Mode_SVC        EQU     0x13
Mode_ABT        EQU     0x17
Mode_UND        EQU     0x1B
Mode_SYS        EQU     0x1F

I_Bit           EQU     0x80            ; when I bit is set, IRQ is disabled
F_Bit           EQU     0x40            ; when F bit is set, FIQ is disabled


;// <h> Stack Configuration (Stack Sizes in Bytes)
;//   <o0> Undefined Mode      <0x0-0xFFFFFFFF:8>
;//   <o1> Supervisor Mode     <0x0-0xFFFFFFFF:8>
;//   <o2> Abort Mode          <0x0-0xFFFFFFFF:8>
;//   <o3> Fast Interrupt Mode <0x0-0xFFFFFFFF:8>
;//   <o4> Interrupt Mode      <0x0-0xFFFFFFFF:8>
;//   <o5> User/System Mode    <0x0-0xFFFFFFFF:8>
;// </h>

UND_Stack_Size  EQU     0x00000000
SVC_Stack_Size  EQU     0x00000008
ABT_Stack_Size  EQU     0x00000000
FIQ_Stack_Size  EQU     0x00000000
IRQ_Stack_Size  EQU     0x00000080
USR_Stack_Size  EQU     0x00000400

ISR_Stack_Size  EQU     (UND_Stack_Size + SVC_Stack_Size + ABT_Stack_Size + \
                         FIQ_Stack_Size + IRQ_Stack_Size)

                AREA    STACK, NOINIT, READWRITE, ALIGN=3

Stack_Mem       SPACE   USR_Stack_Size
__initial_sp    SPACE   ISR_Stack_Size

Stack_Top


;// <h> Heap Configuration
;//   <o>  Heap Size (in Bytes) <0x0-0xFFFFFFFF>
;// </h>

Heap_Size       EQU     0x00000000

                AREA    HEAP, NOINIT, READWRITE, ALIGN=3
__heap_base
Heap_Mem        SPACE   Heap_Size
__heap_limit


; VPBDIV definitions
VPBDIV          EQU     0xE01FC100      ; VPBDIV Address

;// <e> VPBDIV Setup
;// <i> Peripheral Bus Clock Rate
;//   <o1.0..1>   VPBDIV: VPB Clock
;//               <0=> VPB Clock = CPU Clock / 4
;//               <1=> VPB Clock = CPU Clock
;//               <2=> VPB Clock = CPU Clock / 2
;//   <o1.4..5>   XCLKDIV: XCLK Pin
;//               <0=> XCLK Pin = CPU Clock / 4
;//               <1=> XCLK Pin = CPU Clock
;//               <2=> XCLK Pin = CPU Clock / 2
;// </e>
VPBDIV_SETUP    EQU     0
VPBDIV_Val      EQU     0x00000000


; Phase Locked Loop (PLL) definitions
PLL_BASE        EQU     0xE01FC080      ; PLL Base Address
PLLCON_OFS      EQU     0x00            ; PLL Control Offset
PLLCFG_OFS      EQU     0x04            ; PLL Configuration Offset
PLLSTAT_OFS     EQU     0x08            ; PLL Status Offset
PLLFEED_OFS     EQU     0x0C            ; PLL Feed Offset
PLLCON_PLLE     EQU     (1<<0)          ; PLL Enable
PLLCON_PLLC     EQU     (1<<1)          ; PLL Connect
PLLCFG_MSEL     EQU     (0x1F<<0)       ; PLL Multiplier
PLLCFG_PSEL     EQU     (0x03<<5)       ; PLL Divider
PLLSTAT_PLOCK   EQU     (1<<10)         ; PLL Lock Status

;// <e> PLL Setup
;//   <o1.0..4>   MSEL: PLL Multiplier Selection
;//               <1-32><#-1>
;//               <i> M Value
;//   <o1.5..6>   PSEL: PLL Divider Selection
;//               <0=> 1   <1=> 2   <2=> 4   <3=> 8
;//               <i> P Value
;// </e>
PLL_SETUP       EQU     1
PLLCFG_Val      EQU     0x00000024


; Memory Accelerator Module (MAM) definitions
MAM_BASE        EQU     0xE01FC000      ; MAM Base Address
MAMCR_OFS       EQU     0x00            ; MAM Control Offset
MAMTIM_OFS      EQU     0x04            ; MAM Timing Offset

;// <e> MAM Setup
;//   <o1.0..1>   MAM Control
;//               <0=> Disabled
;//               <1=> Partially Enabled
;//               <2=> Fully Enabled
;//               <i> Mode
;//   <o2.0..2>   MAM Timing
;//               <0=> Reserved  <1=> 1   <2=> 2   <3=> 3
;//               <4=> 4         <5=> 5   <6=> 6   <7=> 7
;//               <i> Fetch Cycles
;// </e>
MAM_SETUP       EQU     1
MAMCR_Val       EQU     0x00000002
MAMTIM_Val      EQU     0x00000004


; External Memory Controller (EMC) definitions
EMC_BASE        EQU     0xFFE00000      ; EMC Base Address
BCFG0_OFS       EQU     0x00            ; BCFG0 Offset
BCFG1_OFS       EQU     0x04            ; BCFG1 Offset
BCFG2_OFS       EQU     0x08            ; BCFG2 Offset
BCFG3_OFS       EQU     0x0C            ; BCFG3 Offset

;// <e> External Memory Controller (EMC)
EMC_SETUP       EQU     0

;//   <e> Bank Configuration 0 (BCFG0)
;//     <o1.0..3>   IDCY: Idle Cycles <0-15>
;//     <o1.5..9>   WST1: Wait States 1 <0-31>
;//     <o1.11..15> WST2: Wait States 2 <0-31>
;//     <o1.10>     RBLE: Read Byte Lane Enable
;//     <o1.26>     WP: Write Protect
;//     <o1.27>     BM: Burst ROM
;//     <o1.28..29> MW: Memory Width  <0=>  8-bit  <1=> 16-bit
;//                                   <2=> 32-bit  <3=> Reserved
;//   </e>
BCFG0_SETUP EQU         0
BCFG0_Val   EQU         0x0000FBEF

;//   <e> Bank Configuration 1 (BCFG1)
;//     <o1.0..3>   IDCY: Idle Cycles <0-15>
;//     <o1.5..9>   WST1: Wait States 1 <0-31>
;//     <o1.11..15> WST2: Wait States 2 <0-31>
;//     <o1.10>     RBLE: Read Byte Lane Enable
;//     <o1.26>     WP: Write Protect
;//     <o1.27>     BM: Burst ROM
;//     <o1.28..29> MW: Memory Width  <0=>  8-bit  <1=> 16-bit
;//                                   <2=> 32-bit  <3=> Reserved
;//   </e>
BCFG1_SETUP EQU         0
BCFG1_Val   EQU         0x0000FBEF

;//   <e> Bank Configuration 2 (BCFG2)
;//     <o1.0..3>   IDCY: Idle Cycles <0-15>
;//     <o1.5..9>   WST1: Wait States 1 <0-31>
;//     <o1.11..15> WST2: Wait States 2 <0-31>
;//     <o1.10>     RBLE: Read Byte Lane Enable
;//     <o1.26>     WP: Write Protect
;//     <o1.27>     BM: Burst ROM
;//     <o1.28..29> MW: Memory Width  <0=>  8-bit  <1=> 16-bit
;//                                   <2=> 32-bit  <3=> Reserved
;//   </e>
BCFG2_SETUP EQU         0
BCFG2_Val   EQU         0x0000FBEF

;//   <e> Bank Configuration 3 (BCFG3)
;//     <o1.0..3>   IDCY: Idle Cycles <0-15>
;//     <o1.5..9>   WST1: Wait States 1 <0-31>
;//     <o1.11..15> WST2: Wait States 2 <0-31>
;//     <o1.10>     RBLE: Read Byte Lane Enable
;//     <o1.26>     WP: Write Protect
;//     <o1.27>     BM: Burst ROM
;//     <o1.28..29> MW: Memory Width  <0=>  8-bit  <1=> 16-bit
;//                                   <2=> 32-bit  <3=> Reserved
;//   </e>
BCFG3_SETUP EQU         0
BCFG3_Val   EQU         0x0000FBEF

;// </e> End of EMC


; External Memory Pins definitions
PINSEL2         EQU     0xE002C014      ; PINSEL2 Address
PINSEL2_Val     EQU     0x0E6149E4      ; CS0..3, OE, WE, BLS0..3, 
                                        ; D0..31, A2..23, JTAG Pins


                PRESERVE8


; Area Definition and Entry Point
;  Startup Code must be linked first at Address at which it expects to run.

                AREA    RESET, CODE, READONLY
                ARM


; Exception Vectors
;  Mapped to Address 0.
;  Absolute addressing mode must be used.
;  Dummy Handlers are implemented as infinite loops which can be modified.

Vectors         LDR     PC, Reset_Addr         
                LDR     PC, Undef_Addr
                LDR     PC, SWI_Addr
                LDR     PC, PAbt_Addr
                LDR     PC, DAbt_Addr
                NOP                            ; Reserved Vector 
;               LDR     PC, IRQ_Addr
                LDR     PC, [PC, #-0x0FF0]     ; Vector from VicVectAddr
                LDR     PC, FIQ_Addr

Reset_Addr      DCD     Reset_Handler
Undef_Addr      DCD     Undef_Handler
SWI_Addr        DCD     SWI_Handler
PAbt_Addr       DCD     PAbt_Handler
DAbt_Addr       DCD     DAbt_Handler
                DCD     0                      ; Reserved Address 
IRQ_Addr        DCD     IRQ_Handler
FIQ_Addr        DCD     FIQ_Handler

Undef_Handler   B       Undef_Handler
SWI_Handler     B       SWI_Handler
PAbt_Handler    B       PAbt_Handler
DAbt_Handler    B       DAbt_Handler
IRQ_Handler     B       IRQ_Handler
FIQ_Handler     B       FIQ_Handler


; Reset Handler

                EXPORT  Reset_Handler
Reset_Handler   


; Setup External Memory Pins
                IF      :DEF:EXTERNAL_MODE
                LDR     R0, =PINSEL2
                LDR     R1, =PINSEL2_Val
                STR     R1, [R0]
                ENDIF


; Setup External Memory Controller
                IF      EMC_SETUP <> 0
                LDR     R0, =EMC_BASE

                IF      BCFG0_SETUP <> 0
                LDR     R1, =BCFG0_Val
                STR     R1, [R0, #BCFG0_OFS]
                ENDIF

                IF      BCFG1_SETUP <> 0
                LDR     R1, =BCFG1_Val
                STR     R1, [R0, #BCFG1_OFS]
                ENDIF

                IF      BCFG2_SETUP <> 0
                LDR     R1, =BCFG2_Val
                STR     R1, [R0, #BCFG2_OFS]
                ENDIF

                IF      BCFG3_SETUP <> 0
                LDR     R1, =BCFG3_Val
                STR     R1, [R0, #BCFG3_OFS]
                ENDIF

                ENDIF   ; EMC_SETUP


; Setup VPBDIV
                IF      VPBDIV_SETUP <> 0
                LDR     R0, =VPBDIV
                LDR     R1, =VPBDIV_Val
                STR     R1, [R0]
                ENDIF


; Setup PLL
                IF      PLL_SETUP <> 0
                LDR     R0, =PLL_BASE
                MOV     R1, #0xAA
                MOV     R2, #0x55

;  Configure and Enable PLL
                MOV     R3, #PLLCFG_Val
                STR     R3, [R0, #PLLCFG_OFS] 
                MOV     R3, #PLLCON_PLLE
                STR     R3, [R0, #PLLCON_OFS]
                STR     R1, [R0, #PLLFEED_OFS]
                STR     R2, [R0, #PLLFEED_OFS]

;  Wait until PLL Locked
PLL_Loop        LDR     R3, [R0, #PLLSTAT_OFS]
                ANDS    R3, R3, #PLLSTAT_PLOCK
                BEQ     PLL_Loop

;  Switch to PLL Clock
                MOV     R3, #(PLLCON_PLLE:OR:PLLCON_PLLC)
                STR     R3, [R0, #PLLCON_OFS]
                STR     R1, [R0, #PLLFEED_OFS]
                STR     R2, [R0, #PLLFEED_OFS]
                ENDIF   ; PLL_SETUP


; Setup MAM
                IF      MAM_SETUP <> 0
                LDR     R0, =MAM_BASE
                MOV     R1, #MAMTIM_Val
                STR     R1, [R0, #MAMTIM_OFS] 
                MOV     R1, #MAMCR_Val
                STR     R1, [R0, #MAMCR_OFS] 
                ENDIF   ; MAM_SETUP


; Memory Mapping (when Interrupt Vectors are in RAM)
MEMMAP          EQU     0xE01FC040      ; Memory Mapping Control
                IF      :DEF:REMAP
                LDR     R0, =MEMMAP
                IF      :DEF:EXTMEM_MODE
                MOV     R1, #3
                ELIF    :DEF:RAM_MODE
                MOV     R1, #2
                ELSE
                MOV     R1, #1
                ENDIF
                STR     R1, [R0]
                ENDIF


; Initialise Interrupt System
;  ...


; Setup Stack for each mode

                LDR     R0, =Stack_Top

;  Enter Undefined Instruction Mode and set its Stack Pointer
                MSR     CPSR_c, #Mode_UND:OR:I_Bit:OR:F_Bit
                MOV     SP, R0
                SUB     R0, R0, #UND_Stack_Size

;  Enter Abort Mode and set its Stack Pointer
                MSR     CPSR_c, #Mode_ABT:OR:I_Bit:OR:F_Bit
                MOV     SP, R0
                SUB     R0, R0, #ABT_Stack_Size

;  Enter FIQ Mode and set its Stack Pointer
                MSR     CPSR_c, #Mode_FIQ:OR:I_Bit:OR:F_Bit
                MOV     SP, R0
                SUB     R0, R0, #FIQ_Stack_Size

;  Enter IRQ Mode and set its Stack Pointer
                MSR     CPSR_c, #Mode_IRQ:OR:I_Bit:OR:F_Bit
                MOV     SP, R0
                SUB     R0, R0, #IRQ_Stack_Size

;  Enter Supervisor Mode and set its Stack Pointer
                MSR     CPSR_c, #Mode_SVC:OR:I_Bit:OR:F_Bit
                MOV     SP, R0
                SUB     R0, R0, #SVC_Stack_Size

;  Enter User Mode and set its Stack Pointer
                MSR     CPSR_c, #Mode_USR
                IF      :DEF:__MICROLIB

                EXPORT __initial_sp

                ELSE

                MOV     SP, R0
                SUB     SL, SP, #USR_Stack_Size

                ENDIF


; Enter the C code

                IMPORT  __main
                LDR     R0, =__main
                BX      R0


                IF      :DEF:__MICROLIB

                EXPORT  __heap_base
                EXPORT  __heap_limit

                ELSE
; User Initial Stack & Heap
                AREA    |.text|, CODE, READONLY

                IMPORT  __use_two_region_memory
                EXPORT  __user_initial_stackheap
__user_initial_stackheap

                LDR     R0, =  Heap_Mem
                LDR     R1, =(Stack_Mem + USR_Stack_Size)
                LDR     R2, = (Heap_Mem +      Heap_Size)
                LDR     R3, = Stack_Mem
                BX      LR
                ENDIF


                END
```

Unfortunately I am just starting to learn assembly, so I have no idea what this code does, but more important how to fix the problem. 
Here problematic line

```
; Enter the C code

                IMPORT  __main
                LDR     R0, =__main
                BX      R0


                IF      :DEF:__MICROLIB

                EXPORT  __heap_base
                EXPORT  __heap_limit

                ELSE
```

As I can guess here main function is being called, but as far as I am writing assembly program, it throws me an error that I have no section main.

What is the correct way to start execution of my custom code from this startup.

I know that I can name my area `RESET` and it will goes here, but I want to do this in right way.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

This code works just fine

```
        AREA Factorial, CODE, READONLY
        EXPORT __main
        ENTRY
__main
        MOV r0, #10 ; load initial value
        MOV r1, #1 ; if n=0 than 1 is result
loop    CMP r0, #0 ; if n=0
        MULGT r1, r0, r1
        SUBGT r0, r0, #1
        BGT loop
stop    B stop ; stop program
        END
```

Thank you 
But only one warning

```
.\Objects\SortingAlgorithm.sct(8): warning: L6314W: No section matches pattern *(InRoot$$Sections).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually all that code is used to initialize the processor (set a stack for your push/pop operations, set vector for exceptions, clocks...) and initialize the "C" runtime (prepare a heap, initialize the variables for the runtime etc), but in general you can forget about these things. Please note that 
Nevertheless, all the programs in "C" starts with a function called "main" or really "_main", so that piece of code is looking for a symbol called on that way.

If you get your example code and declare a public label called "_main", you should be able to execute your code when your target (your board) boots!

So, something like that should make it work:

```
   AREA Prog1, CODE, READONLY
EXPORT  __main
;        ENTRY  <= You do not need to declare an entry point
__main
    MOV r0, #0x11 ; load initial value
    LSL r1, r0, #1 ; shift 1 bit left
    LSL r2, r1, #1 ; shift 1 bit left
stop    B stop ; stop program
    END
```

Please note that I did not test that code! But as an starting point you can start with this.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for answers, it compiles, but I have several warnings 
`.\Objects\SortingAlgorithm.axf: Warning: L6305W: Image does not have an entry point. (Not specified or not set due to multiple choices.)` 
and `.\Objects\SortingAlgorithm.sct(8): warning: L6314W: No section matches pattern *(InRoot$$Sections).` 

What does this mean and how can I fix this ?

Comment: Maybe I was wrong, remove the comment (";") in the ENTRY sentence. Really its meaning less, because entry sections are used for application loaders, that is, when you write a program (AXF/ELF) file that have to be loaded by an operating system. In your case, you are using a image stored on flash, but, the linker complains that the entry point is not found.
Just remove the comment and check it.

Comment: @juasolsona thanks for comment first error has gone, but one last error is still present in the output

I update my answer with current code, what is the problem ? Maybe there is a way do not use C runtime at all ?

Comment: Please, paste de output from the linker, cannot see the error.

Comment: `.\Objects\SortingAlgorithm.sct(8): warning: L6314W: No section matches pattern *(InRoot$$Sections). `

I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

That is not an important issue, nevertheless if you do not like to see it, just rename your section as follows:

```
AREA InRoot$$Sections, CODE, READONLY
;    AREA InRoot, CODE, READONLY <= Maybe that is the syntax
EXPORT  __main
ENTRY  
 __main
     MOV r0, #0x11 ; load initial value
     LSL r1, r0, #1 ; shift 1 bit left
     LSL r2, r1, #1 ; shift 1 bit left
 stop    B stop ; stop program
     END
```

(Once again, I did not test that, it may be that the section have to be called just "InRoot")

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

add this to the Linker tab -> Misc controls
--diag_suppress=L6314W

you can find more in this page:
[https://web.eece.maine.edu/~zhu/book/faq.php#L6314W](https://web.eece.maine.edu/%7Ezhu/book/faq.php#L6314W)